# Sum and calculate percentages of cells with specific values

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to develop a marking sheet that will return percentages of checked cells, but discard any unchecked cells.

So far I've got the checked cells done - I assigned checked cells a value of 10 and unchecked cells a value of 0 (I have 10 questions, so if someone gets everything right, they get a score of 100). I'm trying to write 3 formulas, all of which only consider the checked cells, excluding anything unchecked. The formula's I want are:

1. Total (=sum)
2. Average (=average)
3. Median (=median)

I'm fairly confident that I can use 'if' (e.g., =sumif) or filter (e.g., sum(filter...)), but I have no idea of the exact syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried to find the answer on Google but I'm fairly new to this sort of thing so I'm not 100% sure what to look for.

Added an image below showing my data. I'd like to have something that only considers calculates percentage based off a cell with a 0 or 10 in it, ignoring any cells with N/A (I realized a checkbox wouldn't work as I need 3 values - (1) pass [10], (2) fail [0] or (3) not applicable [N/A]; but a checkbox can only have 2 values).

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome. I'm not sure of the syntax either because I can't visualise your data. Would you please take two screenshots and include them in your answer: 1) showing your data (names changed to protect the innocent), and 2) one with a view of how a successful outcome would appear./

Comment: Added an image if that helps.

Comment: Please share your spreadsheet file

Comment: You should be aware that if you share your spreadsheet, then your email address will be unavoidably exposed.